# Basic EE file upload hangs

Tags: file-uploads

So I am having trouble with a simple feature. I am running 2.8.1 and I have a channel file field that uploads an image. The image is only 200k.

I pick the image, click upload and the upload window just hangs. If I cancel and relaod the page, the file I was trying to upload is listed in the available images list so it made it to the server, the upload page just never closed. Happens on all images.

Any ideas what I can check?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Check that your file upload directory settings are correct (Content > Files > File Upload Preferences > "Edit" link) and the folders on the server have their permissions set to 777. You can even try manually (via FTP) adding an image to the folder and then sync in EE to see if it's reading that directory properly.

Comment: Yep, 777. The files do get uploaded when the page is hanging, so I don't think its a permission thing. Its like the upload form just never gets the notice that the file is done uploading. Channel images works fine though.

Comment: Any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with Expression Engine 2.9.11. The upload process would hang but the image would still upload successfully. It's just the little upload window wouldn't close. Refreshing the admin page would show the image was uploaded.

While troubleshooting a different issue (on IIS) I increased the values for these 4 items and that introduced the EE upload problem. Reverting these 4 values back to what we had before fixed the EE upload problem.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with one of these php.ini settings. This is what I have now for these 4 values and it's working.

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 200M
max_input_time = 60
max_execution_time=300
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem with Channel Images.  The problem was the filename.. i used french character like é è or any other french characters.  Renaming the file on the local computer before the upload was the solution.